# one-to-many relationships in sequelizer

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Been looking at various answers and git issues and still can't get it to work. I have drivers model and CarDrivers model. A driver can drive multiple cars so I want to create a one-to-many relationships.

Drivers Model is (models/drivers.js):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Driver = sequelize.define('Driver', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Driver.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here

  };
  return Driver;
};
```

now CarDrivers (models/cardrivers.js):

```
'use strict';


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CarDriver = sequelize.define('CarDriver', {
    status: DataTypes.INTEGER,

  }, {});
  CarDriver.associate = function(models) {

    // associations can be defined here
    CarDriver.belongsTo(models.Driver, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: 'id',
      as: 'car_driver'
    });
  };
  return CarDriver;
};
```

Data migration works with no errors but I don't see an entry/related column in table CarDrivers. Anybody can help fix it please.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the `foreign_key` in your association definition cannot be `id`, as that will clash with the `id` of the `CarDriver` table. If you change it to `driver_id`, you will see that column in the `car_driver` table:

```
const Driver = sequelize.define('driver', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});

const CarDriver = sequelize.define('car_driver', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});

CarDriver.belongsTo(Driver, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  foreignKey: 'driver_id'
});

const driver = await Driver.create({
  name: 'first driver'
})

const carDriver = await CarDriver.create({
  name: 'first carDriver',
  driver_id: driver.id
})
```

Two notes:

- `foreignKey` is optional. If you leave it blank, Sequelize will default to camelcase, e.g. `driverId`
- Your migration file must account for the foreign key on the `CarDriver` table:

  ```
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('car_driver', {
      id: {},
      driver_id: {
        ..
      }
    });
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks @mcranston18. Is it absolutely necessary the models be defined in the same file or they can be defined in separate models then import Driver model. I tried importing with const Driver=require('./drivers') and went on to create the relationship but it didn't change.

During migration, I can see Driver is created first then cardriver so I doubt it is missing the model.

Comment: No. They don't have to be in the same file. What specifically doesn't work? I just tried out my code and got the expected results: https://github.com/mcranston18/sequelize-experiments/blob/master/drivers-cars.js

Comment: I still can't see driver_id is the problem after setup. const Driver=require('./driver') doesn't have effect (even wrong path gives no import errors). my current set up is as follows;

models/driver.js defines Driver (in the database, it was changed to drivers)
migrations/date-create-driver.js is its migration

models/cardriver.js defines CarDriver (became CarDrivers in the database)
migration/date-create-car-driver.js is is migration

so in CarDriver, I was hoping to first import Driver and do what you did but no result. I would love to keep the current setup but only if it can work.

Comment: This is my current setup https://github.com/iconicsammy/sequelizer-test

Comment: Yes, but do you see `driverId`? I don't see anywhere in your code that you specified that foreign key should be called `driver_id`

Comment: Sorry for taking your time but yes I tried foreignKey;"driver_id", foreignKey:"driverId" then since i think you mentioned it is optional, tried that too. I am just confused as it generates no errors nor warnings to guide me through. I still can't see driver_id/driverId added to CarDriver module. But my set up is correct? Btw, where do I save the github you shared and is it a migration or just a model.. how would I use it.

Comment: Oh, you must also include `driverId` in your migration file for the `car_driver` table. Add that and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181767/discussion-between-mcranston18-and-nie-selam).